# PostgreSQL - equivalent version of a table declared in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have the following table declared in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

What would be an equivalent definition of the table in postgres, assuming my database is already using UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ci_sessions (
  session_id varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ip_address varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  user_agent varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  last_activity int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  user_data text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

The modifier IF NOT EXISTS has IMHO just been added to one of the newest PostgreSQL versions.

**EDIT**: As unnamed horse recommended, I changed the 4th attribute from decimal(10) to int4. But I would prefer a timestamp(0) here, also. Use just timestamp without the (0) if you need microsecond precision here.

Comment: Hmmm... so `utf8_bin` and `COLLATE` are just extraneous, then?

Comment: It is defined for the whole cluster. No special collations can be given for inidividual columns, at least in 8.4! Let me have a look in the docs for the newer versions. See this link for more info about collation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/locale.html

Comment: Sorry, no news on this. Seems like collation is still settable just for the DB. You can however use special collation settings for indexes, while will be used when you specify the right sort clauses.

Comment: That statement will not work. `DEFAUL '0'` for the column last_activity is illegal for PostgreSQL as `'0'` is a character literal and not a number.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: This works. Implicit casts are your friend. However, obviously it is better when using a decimal directly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Did you test it? The statement executes just fine on my server running postgres 8.3

Comment: Btw. I would prefer my IP address to be null, instead of 0. Just my 2cents

Comment: @Justin Ethier: Sorry, yes it works, but I still consider it bad practise :) (It would throw an error the other way round)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Daniel has already said:

If you need to query on the IP address it might be better to use the native inet datatype for that:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html

The column name last_activity suggests a timestamp column or something similar. I would strongly recommend to use the `timestamp` data type for that.

If it is something different, then `integer` is a better match to MySQL's `int(10)` than decimal.

Note that int(10) in MySQL does **not** define the value range, it's merely a hint for displaying purposes!

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding the hint on int(10), I didn't know MySQL worked like this.

Comment: @Daniel: You might want to consider changing your code example to use int instead of decimal as well.